# Load rows by DATETIME value and timeframe

Tags: mysql, sql

In my mysql database, I insert to a table 100 rows every minute. The column named 'time' is of type DATETIME contains the date & hour of the insertion (excluding seconds). 
I'm looking for an efficient way to fetch rows from that table - in a specified timeframe.
For example, if my timeframe is 15 minutes, then the following rows would be fetched:

```
3-11-18 13:00:00
3-11-18 13:15:00
3-11-18 13:30:00
3-11-18 13:45:00
3-11-18 14:00:00
```

etc...
For timeframe of one hour it will fetch

```
3-11-18 13:00:00
3-11-18 14:00:00
```

Currently, I'm using the LIKE operator to do that. For example, 15 minutes timeframe query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE time LIKE '%:15:00' OR time LIKE '%:30:00' OR time LIKE '%:45:00' OR time LIKE '%:00:00';
```

But these queries run very very slow. 
What can I do to improve performance?

Comment: What version do you use?

Comment: I use version 5.7

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/generated-column-index-optimizations.html

Comment: 1) index time 2) use `HOUR(time) = [minute]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a generated column for minutes and set an index on it:

```
alter table my_table add column minute tinyint unsigned as (minute(time));
alter table my_table add index (minute);
```

A query like

```
select * from my_table where minute(time) = 0;
```

would use that index.

But I'm not sure if it helps with a query like

```
select * from my_table where minute(time) in (0, 15, 30, 45);
```

The reason is that the selectivity of the WHERE condition is not very good here. A full table scan skipping 14 of 15 rows can be faster than an index search + a second round trip to the clustered index. In that case you can't do anything. Except of creating a covering index. But an index that will cover `SELECT *` will be probably harmfull for 100 inserts per minute.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MOD` to filter by the timeframe requirement.

For timeframe of 15 minutes:

```
SELECT * 
from my_table
where mod(minute(time),15) = 0
```

For 30 minutes timeframe:

```
mod(minute(time),30)  = 0
```

For one hour (60-minutes) timeframe:

```
mod(minute(time),60)  = 0
```

Or

```
minute(time) = 0
```

Generalized `WHERE` clause for 15, 30 or 60 minutes timeframe:

```
mod( minute(time), <timeframeInMinutes>) = 0
```